# Connect Samsung Android Phone to Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04

I Cannot Connect Samsung Android Phone to Ubuntu 16.04.  The error says:

"Couldn't find matching UDEV adev device."

The phone will mount but you get an error trying to copy any files.

Samsung pops up a message saying install Kies.

Following instructions I found on Stack Overflow for Ubuntu 140.4 I installed mtpfs libmtp.  But that did not help.

Comment: What did you install? i have a fresh ubuntu 16. phones just charges when i connect USB. android samsumg galaxy j700.

Comment: did not install anything.  As I noted below it just started working, but I did not change anything.  Maybe Ubuntu or Samsung pushed out an update?

Comment: ah I see, nice, i will try update too

Answer (score 2):

For Android devices that use **Android 4.4 or higher**, the correct setting on the device's USB connections menu is **MTP**.  Use that one for file transfers but it's essential that you **unmount** the phone before disconnecting the USB cable when you're finished.

Answer (score 1):

This works now so Ubuntu must have pushed an update.  It works now on two different laptop models and did not work before.  So that must be the case.